# Joomla event doesnt get triggered

Tags: joomla

This is my plugin:

```
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

// Import library dependencies
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgContentEya extends JPlugin
{

 function plgContentEya( &$subject, $config )
 {
    parent::__construct( $subject, $config );

 }
/**
 * Plugin method with the same name as the event will be called automatically.
 */
 function onAfterDisplayContent( &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
 {//Echo script there
echo "script works";
        // Plugin code goes here.
        // You can access parameters via $this->params.
    return "<script src='http://widget.eya.com/sprk.1.0.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
 }
}




http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content
```

According to their documenation

```
  Return Value
String. Returned value from this event will be displayed in a placeholder. Most templates display this placeholder after the article separator.
```

The plugin gets displayed and doesnt throw an error when I install it.. But the event never gets triggered. I dont see it in the document

```
<install version="2.5" type="plugin" group="content">
   <name>plg_content_eya</name>
   <author>eya</author>
   <creationDate>February 2013</creationDate>
   <copyright>(C) 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
   <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
   <authorEmail>anattaligg@graeit.com</authorEmail>
   <authorUrl>www.eya.com</authorUrl>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
   <description>Adds eya plugin ot your site</description>
   <files>
     <filename plugin="eya">eya.php</filename>
   </files>

</install>
```

Comment: Your constructor should be named plgContentEya, the same as the class name. That probably results in parent constructor not being called. Not entirely sure though, but it's worth a try.

Comment: no, sorry it is my typo.. i am not sure what it is.. may be it is the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `version="2.5"` in your XML, your plugin is not being called because you have the wrong event name.

The event names have changed since the [Plugin/Events/Content for Joomla! 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content) document was written. I've marked it as a 1.5 document to make that clear.

Events were renamed to be more consistent (domain/period/event e.g. *Content/After/Display*), so, the event you want is now called `onContentAfterSave` and you can find more information about renamed events in the article "[Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Renamed_Events)"

If you want to support Joomla! 1.5 in your plug-in as well you will also have to add a compatibility layer to catch the 2.5 call and redirect it to your method. e.g.

```php
// Catch 2.5
public function onContentAfterDisplay($article, $params, $limitstart)
{
    $result = $this->onAfterDisplayContent($article, $params, $limitstart);
    return $result;
}
```

*N.B. Not tested code just typed in...*

Comment: Thanks..damn, you are right. They should update their docs..goddammit

Comment: Glad it helped... It's open source, so it's up to us, the users of it to update it when we find it :D